Create a bar graph for complication rates among two cohorts
I'm trying to design a bar graph that represents percentages of complications among two cohorts (GLP and No GLP). I am using the data table and code below, and I have included my current result as well as a depiction of the graph I'm trying to obtain.
Any help would be appreciated. Data table below saved as GLPcomprate.



Cohort
Complication
Percentage




GLP
CSF_leak
13.40


GLP
DVT
5.74


GLP
UTI
20.57


GLP
Constipation
22.97


GLP
Pneumonia
9.09


GLP
Post-operative Infection
6.22


GLP
Adverse Drug Effects
4.79


GLP
Meningitis
4.79


GLP
Post-operative Respiratory Failure
4.79


GLP
Thyrotoxicosis
4.79


GLP
Acute Kidney Injury
11.96


GLP
Delirium
4.79


No GLP
CSF_leak
11.32


No GLP
DVT
5.26


No GLP
UTI
15.74


No GLP
Constipation
24.73


No GLP
Pneumonia
9.81


No GLP
Post-operative Infection
5.26


No GLP
Adverse Drug Effects
0.65


No GLP
Meningitis
7.12


No GLP
Post-operative Respiratory Failure
1.71


No GLP
Thyrotoxicosis
1.00


No GLP
Acute Kidney Injury
10.78


No GLP
Delirium
2.46



Current code is below:
GLPcomprate <- read_excel("IIH_GLP_Years.xlsx", sheet = 6)
head(GLPcomprate)

ggplot(GLPcomprate, aes(x=Complication, y=Percentage, fill = Cohort)) +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack(), width = 1) +
         geom_text(aes(label = paste(Percentage, "%")), vjust = -1) +
facet_wrap(~Cohort, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") + 
theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside ")

Current output:

Desired output (created on Excel):


Just use position_dodge(). The result from the ggplot2 defaults made the plot cluttered so I have added some adjustments, tweak where necessary. Also, there was a typo in your example data, remember R is case-sensitive.
library(ggplot2)

# Data
GLPcomprate <- read.table(text = "Cohort,Complication,Percentage
GLP,CSF_leak,13.40
GLP,DVT,5.74
GLP,UTI,20.57
GLP,Constipation,22.97
GLP,Pneumonia,9.09
GLP,Post-operative Infection,6.22
GLP,Adverse Drug Effects,4.79
GLP,Meningitis,4.79
GLP,Post-operative Respiratory Failure,4.79
GLP,Thyrotoxicosis,4.79
GLP,Acute Kidney Injury,11.96
GLP,Delirium,4.79
No GLP,CSF_leak,11.32
No GLP,DVT,5.26
No GLP,UTI,15.74
No GLP,Constipation,24.73
No GLP,Pneumonia,9.81
No GLP,Post-operative Infection,5.26
No GLP,Adverse Drug Effects,0.65
No GLP,Meningitis,7.12
No GLP,Post-operative Respiratory Failure,1.71
No GLP,Thyrotoxicosis,1.00
No GLP,Acute Kidney Injury,10.78
No GLP,Delirium,2.46", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

ggplot(GLPcomprate, 
       aes(x = Complication, y = Percentage, fill = Cohort)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Percentage, "%")),
            size = 2,
            hjust = 0.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside ",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 6))



ggplot(GLPcomprate, aes(fct_inorder(Complication), y=Percentage, fill = Cohort)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = 0.4) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.01), limits = c(0, 30), breaks = seq(0, 30, 5)) +
  ggthemes::scale_fill_excel_new(labels = c('GLP Percentage', 'No GLP Percentage')) +
  ggthemes::theme_excel_new() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  ) +
  labs(title = 'Complication Rate Among Cohorts')


